# How are sites sorted in the all sites in the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: discussion, android-app, sorting

The list of Stack Exchange sites within **more Stack Exchange communities** are sorted in *ascending order* in the dropdown like below.

[image]

Whereas in the Stack Exchange Android app, it is *not sorted in ascending order*.

First I thought it was sorted based on "live" and "beta" sites. But after scrolling down I found a few more "live" sites are in between the "beta" sites.

Here is a screenshot from the app.

[image]

While writing this question I found the sort pattern is quite similar as of in [all sites in Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites). But this doesn't make any sense in app.

Can we follow a common sorting approach in both site and app?

Answer (score 4):

The sites are currently displayed in the default order from the [API call](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) which is by site id.

It might make more sense to display them in alphabetic order like the websites. However I personally think searching on mobile devices is a bit more bothersome than searching on computers, so it might be better to leave it as is so that the most-used (AKA oldest) sites are higher up in the list before someone searches.

Comment: You have filters for All/Main/Meta. Why not have sorting too?

Comment: @mhlester maybe, i cant quite imagine how to display that without getting a confused UI though.

Comment: Yeah, me neither. Good luck! :-P

Comment: The seemingly random order really bothers me and makes it especially hard to find sites by scrolling through the list. Ordering by an invisible ID is really bad UX. Please change this to a default alphabetic order.

Comment: Not to mention it's inconsistent with the way the sites are shown on the desktop browser (alphabetically).

Comment: Please alphabetize them. Currently it's really hard to find one in the long list. As an ordinary user, I'm not familiar with all the sites, nor their ages and API ids, and I shouldn't have to be. It's also confusing that the list of Meta sites is sorted differently (I'd make it match the main list 1:1 even though some site names are "Meta X" while others are "X Meta") and put Meta SE in the Meta list with all the other Meta sites.

Comment: It does not seem that something happened to this issue in quite some time, but I too find it very annoying that the sites don't appear ordered at all. Maybe we could add a feature that orders sites alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

The ordering preferences of "Your sites" left menu list on the app is saved as a number (the order that you have) concatenated with the name of the site, for example "1_meta", "0_stackoverflow" or "12_meta.gaming". The lowest order number is 0.

To order, that string is simply ordered, without taking in account that it should be ordered as numbers. When you order like that (and ignoring the site name part), for 13 items, instead of having an ordered list of "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12" you get "0 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9". That's because `0 < 10 < 11 < .. < 19 < 1 < 20 < 2`, I mean, 10 is after 0, but before 1 and 20 would be before 2.

The problem only happens when you have more than 10 sites.

The answer was posted in a different question on this site [“Your Sites” in Android left sidebar shown in unpredictable order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234376/your-sites-in-android-left-sidebar-shown-in-unpredictable-order), in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276326/313476) and it's a bug. Here's the full answer:

> This will be fixed in 1.0.84.
>
> Andrew's description was right on the nose.  When preferences are
>   saved, they are stored in a `HashSet<String>` (who knows why?) which
>   would look something like this:
>
> ```
> 1_meta
> 9_hermeneutics
> 8_patents
> 10_coffee
> 2_math
> 11_photo
> 0_stackoverflow
> 4_bricks
> 12_meta.gaming
> 5_ja.stackoverflow
> 7_pt.stackoverflow
> 3_cooking
> 6_meta.ja.stackoverflow
> ```
>
> A naïve `Collections.sort` was applied which gets us the incorrect
>   ordering:
>
> ```
> 0_stackoverflow 10_coffee 11_photo
> 12_meta.gaming 1_meta 2_math 3_cooking 4_bricks
> 5_ja.stackoverflow 6_meta.ja.stackoverflow 7_pt.stackoverflow
> 8_patents 9_hermeneutics
> ```
>
> Now instead I'm breaking the list into `(int, String)` pair, sorting
>   by the index, and returning the name:
>
> ```
> return Bite.from(siteNamesAndIndexes)
>     .map(SiteIndexPair::new)
>     .sortBy(SiteIndexPair::getIndex)
>     .map(SiteIndexPair::getName).toArrayList();
> ```

Comment: The question is not about "Your sites", but the general "All SE sites" list. Kasra's (the SE Android app developer) has explained that this is due to the API call. There's no further sorting after getting the result for this one.