# Can't re-order favorite sites list on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I've been trying for a while (months) to fix my favorite sites list in the Android app. It neither matches my in browser list nor any sensible order I pick.

The usual issue is that while some sites will re-order, others appear to be stuck where the want to be. No matter what order I drag them to they revert to where they were when I close the editor and return to the app.

Today the problem has morphed to a message that simply says it cannot save my preferences. Is this a problem with the app, the backend, my account or my usage?

Answer (score 1):

This has morphed (now most sites show in order) but there are always still some out of order. Compare for example the ordering I've selected and the order they are showing in.

[image]

Comment: The order bug is a known issue, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273630/241919