# "Your Sites" list entries are of enormous height on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, communities-list

With the update to 1.0.85, the site icons on navigation drawer were rearranged. I can't really discover how the new order was chosen. At least it's the same for tablet and smartphone.

When I choose 'Edit', the list entries are of enormous height. This is also common for both tablet and smartphone.

[image: select site to pin]

Comment: The order should be "ordered" as per [this bug fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276326/241919).